# Как в функции указать один из аргументов, если он с пробелом?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

> Я учусь пользоваться discord.py и у меня возник вопрос.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, text):
    await member.send(text)
    print('from '+ ctx.author.name + ' to ' + member.name + ': ' + text)
```

> Существует такая функция, в которую я указываю пользователя и текст, который хочу отправить.
>
> Вызов функции выглядит примерно так: 1send histor#8461 некоторый текст который я хочу отправить
> Получается пользователь это: histor#8461, а всё остальное текст.
>
> А что если никнейм пользователя состоит из двух или более слов?
> Тогда например в запросе: 1send young histor#8461 некоторый текст который я хочу отправить
> Пользователем будет является: "young", а текстом "histor#8461
> некоторый текст который я хочу отправить"
> В таком случае discord.py выдаст ошибку
>
> Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Покажите вызов функции

Comment: вы же в функцию передаете значение. Логин скорей всего в виде строки, соответственно function ('user name#1235'). Если к логину что-то нужно дописать, например, сообщение, то скорей всего это будет как-то так function ('user name#1235', 'message'). Но все же хотелось бы увидеть функцию и доступные аргументы для нее, мб она вообще словарь принимает в котором группируются и логин, и сообщение и все что угодно

Comment: 1send Kornelius Wagner#4517 Ты теперь подопытный кролик - пример вызова функции
1send - это префикс + название команды

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант самый простой.

Вы можете принимать пользователя в качестве аргумента `member: discord.Member`. Тогда отметив пользователя `@young histor` будет не важно есть пробелы в тексте или нет.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, text): #!send @young histor text
```

Второй способ:

Взять аргумент, в нашем случае `member`, в кавычки.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, member, *, text): #!send '@young histor' text
    user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, member)
```